# Hibernate create child of OneToMany by passing only id of "parent" entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, parent-child

I'm writing a JEE7 JAX-RS REST API backed by Hibernate on top of PostgreSQL.

I have a `Course` entity to which people can register by creating a `Registration`.
Table `registrations` has a foreign-key `course_id` referencing `courses.id`.

These are the entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="courses")
@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
public class Course {

    // ... other properties omitted for brevitiy ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    @OrderBy("updated_at DESC")
    private List<Registration> registrations;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "registrations")
@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
public class Registration {

    // ... other properties omitted for brevitiy ...

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "course_id", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(19, 0)", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long courseId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;
}
```

`Registration.courseId` `@Column` annotation specifies `insertable = false, updatable = false`, because otherwise I can't deploy the application due to a `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity`.

Naturally if I try to persist `Registration` with a `courseId` column, its value are not included in the SQL INSERT statement generated by Hibernate (insertable=false).

Currently I fetch the whole `Course` entity by the `courseId` and pass it to `Registration.setCourse` to successfully create a `Registration`, but I'm looking for a way to avoid this manual "patching" for all `@ManyToOne` associations that I will create for this application.

How define my entities so, that I can persist a `Registration` by setting only `courseId` instead of providing the whole "parent" `Course` in `Registration.course`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your `Registration` entity in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "registrations")
@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
public class Registration {

    // ... 

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "course_id", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(19, 0)")
    private Long courseId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Course course;
}
```